# Eregi and preg_match replacement, big error on capcha and email validator

Tags: php, preg-match, validation, eregi

I know there are a lot of questions related to this subject, but after some days of research I didn't find something that could help this particular case, so here it is:

I have replaced the deprecated eregi with preg_match in 2 files of my website, and now the capcha code gives an error on the registration page, even if the code is absolutely correct

On the registration page I have replaced this

```
function is_valid_username($username) {
    if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]*$", trim(str_replace(" ","",$username)))) {
        return 0;
    }
```

with this

```
if(!preg_match("^[a-z0-9]*$^", trim(str_replace(" ","",$username)))) {
    return 0;
}
```

And in my second file I have replaced this:

```
if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$", $email)) {
    $result = 0;
}
```

with this

```
if(!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$^", $email)) {
    $result = 0;
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: FYI: TLDs are not limited to 4 character length, see: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eregi` is case-insensitive, so you would need to add the `i` modifier to the end of your `preg_match` expression.

Also, `^` denotes the start of the input and you have used it as the [delimiter](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

So this should be more like the original:

```
#^[a-z0-9]*$#i
```

and

```
#^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$#i
```

By the way, I don't know what your captcha code requires exactly, but there are easier ways to verify an email address using [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Comment: Thanks, i have replaced them as suggested but the same result

Comment: @KlaussGekker The code you provided and that I adapted, is not related to the captcha but to the username and email, so the error with the captcha is probably somewhere else.

Comment: I have now noticed that it doesnt give error if i leave the captcha field emtpty... strange..

Comment: @KlaussGekker That's not good :-)